# Load controllers on demand in SPA - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I am new to the whole SPA thing, but i interested of develop one.
All the tutorials on the web has 2 controllers that are included inside the main page.
My question is what is the best practice to load the controllers on demand, 
for example, if i have 5 pages (called partials in SPA world), each one of them has different logic. so i will have 5 controllers, one for each page. I don't think that load all the 5 controllers in the main page is the good method, so how can i load angularJS controller on demand? and how can i unload the controller that was used in the previous "pages"?

if someone has a good tutorial for spa with angular that has more than 2-3 controllers, i will be happy for a link.

Comment: doubtful that 5 controllers amount to a lot of code that you would be saving much overhead just loading them once

Comment: 5 is for example, what if the app is more complicated and has 20 controllers? and not all of them needed in all the pages...

Comment: Are you talking about the literal .js files or the actual binding of a controller to a view/element?

Comment: what are the file size savings you are talking about? Have you done any math on this? Also have you researched using `require.js` and angular? Question seems very hypothetical with limited research done. If you are new to all this.... likely best to spend time using and learning the basics first...then when need to lazy load work it out then

Comment: pretty sure this is why he is asking the question @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

i think that this blog post answers my question, [AngularJS + RequireJS](http://www.startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs/)

Answer (score 0):

We have achieved that using ocLazyLoader. It is dependent states, and for each state you will have to specify the js files to be loaded.
Here is the link https://oclazyload.readme.io/

Although, I would suggest to use minification of the files using grunt or other tool. This would help in increasing the performance as well because network data transfer is not an issue anymore, but to open a connection to server is time consuming. So, its better to minify and load everything at once.